# МолодЕц и мОлодец

Tags: этимология

Когда мы хотим кого-то похвалить, то говорим "молодец". При этом в русских былинах всегда присутствует добрый мОлодец, то есть герой, богатырь.
Интересно, само слово "молодец" происходит исключительно от "молодости"? То есть мОлодец - это просто молодой человек? И если так, то почему "молодЕц" - это похвала, да еще и со смещенным ударением?
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в этих словах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) МолодЕц - молодой человек, достигший расцвета лет, крепкий и статный. Плечистый, здоровый м. Стройные, бравые молодцы. Сравнить: глупый - глупец, храбрый - храбрец, удалой - удалец, но: старый - старец, суффикс ЕЦ может быть ударным или безударным.

2) МОлодец (Нар.-поэт.) - сильный и смелый герой; удалец, храбрец. Буйный, удалой м. Сказка про доброго мОлодца. Добрый молодец должен быть не только молодым, но и смелым героем. Добавилось новое значение, и сместилось ударение.

Но возможны варианты с ударением и на втором слоге: купец-удалой молодец, храбрец-молодец.

3) МолодЕц! О том, чьи действия вызвали одобрение, удовлетворение у кого-л. (по отношению к лицам обоего пола.) Переносное значение, похвала.

Comment: МолодЕц  в  первом  значении  никогда  встречал,  только  в  третьем.

Comment: Молодость  -  прекрасна!  Хорошим  можно  похвалить. Молодой - характеристика,  МолодЕц  -  похвала.

Answer (score 0):

МолодЕц и мОлодец - одно слово. Исходное значение, видимо, "сильный человек". Значение "достойный похвалы" возникло так же, как и у слова "силён" (только "несколько" раньше).
А вот происхождение "молодец" от "молодость", лично у меня, "вызывает смутные сомнения". Уж, скорее, "молодость" - это "возраст силы".

Comment: Мне кажется, что Вы могли бы составить свой толковый и свой этимологический словари. Ваши мнения очень часто и весьма значительно отличаются от общепринятых,которых придерживается ученое сообщество.

Comment: Касательно "молодости", "*учёное сообщество*" **не** придерживается какого-либо мнения. Есть версии происхождения слова "молодой". Все - не слишком убедительные.